# Ask me where to save downloaded pdf

Tags: settings, data-transfer

When I download a file (such as a PDF), rather than prompting me to ask where I want to save the file, it instead downloads the file to `~/Downloads`, then opens the file.

I almost always want to save the file somewhere other than `~/Downloads`, so I always have to use `File -> Move To`, which is an annoying extra step.

I'm pretty sure I said "ok" to some system setting early on which caused this to become the new default behavior, and the behavior is the same on different browsers (Safari, Brave). I'm using MacOS 12.0.1.

Some people suggest right-clicking or holding Control first, but that does not work for example on Google Drive's download button here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/19fe1PeGnggDHymu4LlVY08KmDdhMVRpm/view

How do I make MacOS ask me where to save the file?

Comment: Which application offers a "File->Move To" menu entry?

Comment: @nohillside that would be Preview

Comment: Please don't add answers directly to the question post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some things are easy to overlook. You can change the behaviour in Safari Prefences:

[image]

Google Chrome and Brave have a similar setting in **Settings** > **Advanced** > **Downloads**.

Comment: Google Chrome has a similar setting in **Settings** > **Advanced** > **Downloads** > **Location**.

Comment: ..which can also be opened by going to the settings directly: chrome://settings/downloads

Comment: Found it thanks to this answer and the comments!

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer may help more people with this issue, but I'm adding this Brave-specific answer because it deals with a secondary configuration option which overrides the "Ask where to save" for "certain file types".

Clearing "Open certain file types..." fixed the issue for me:

[image]

As far as I know, this secondary option can only be enabled if you say yes to a prompt when downloading certain file types, such as PDFs.